# ado.net datatable select missing operand after operator

Tags: vb.net, datatable, ado.net

I am getting missing operand error when applying filter to datatable.

The error message is as follows:

```
Syntax error: Missing operand after 'PBRule' operator.

   at System.Data.ExpressionParser.Parse()
   at System.Data.DataExpression..ctor(DataTable table, String expression, Type type)
   at System.Data.DataTable.Select(String filterExpression)
   Dim dr As DataRow()
                        Dim sQuery As String
                        sQuery = "PBRuleId={0} AND StartDate<=#{1:MM/dd/yy}# AND (FinishDate>=#{1:MM/dd/yy}# OR FinishDate IS NULL) AND (SELECT * FROM PBRule WHERE PBCodeID IN (SELECT PBCodeId FROM PBRule WHERE PBHoursTypeId IN (3,4,5,6))"
                        dr = Me.PBRule.PBRule.Select(String.Format(sQuery, .PBRuleId, .PBDate))
```

can any one help

Comment: Your code was looking fine until it go to the part, "AND (SELECT * FROM PBRule ...". You can't SELECT data like that and I am pretty sure you cannot use the IN operator. It isn't SQL SERVER, it's most like ACCESS type syntax.

Comment: @Steve. Thanks for help. I think I need to use LINQ to DataSet in order to get required data row.

Comment: Posted as answer so this can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code was looking fine until it got to the part, "AND (SELECT * FROM PBRule ...". You can't SELECT data like that and I am pretty sure you cannot use the IN operator.

It isn't SQL SERVER, it's most like MS ACCESS type syntax, but not exactly.